# trigger "show Data" from outside iframe

Tags: angular, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, angular7

I am embedding powerBi reports in an angular 7 web application, we are using Powerbi-Client to communicate with the frame and PowerBi. I need two things:

1. How to hide the context menu or prevent the use from using the context menu when right-clicking the report.
2. How can I trigger the "Show Data" Option from outside the IFrame.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For show data you can use the export data:

```
// Get models. models contains enums that can be used.
var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

// Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
var embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

// Get a reference to the embedded report.
report = powerbi.get(embedContainer);

// Retrieve the page collection and get the visuals for the first page.
report.getPages()
  .then(function (pages) {

    // Retrieve active page.
    var activePage = pages.find(function(page) {
      return page.isActive
    });

    activePage.getVisuals()
      .then(function (visuals) {

        // Retrieve the wanted visual.
        var visual = visuals.find(function(visual) {
          return visual.name == "VisualContainer4";
        });

        // Exports visual data
        visual.exportData(models.ExportDataType.Summarized)
          .then(function (result) {
            Log.logCsv(result.data);
          })
          .catch(function (errors) {
            Log.log(errors);
          });
        })
        .catch(function (errors) {
          Log.log(errors);
        });
  })
  .catch(function (errors) {
    Log.log(errors);
  });
            .catch(errors => {
                console.log(errors.message);
            });
```

In the log.logCsv(result.data) you can manipulate the data to do whatever you want with outside the pbi iframe.